# Compare datetime of two different tables and find not between columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have employee shift table, and then attendance table. I would like to know the shifts which the employee has not attended.

Below is the query to create sample tables.

```
DECLARE @InsideOutsideTable TABLE 
(
    FromTime DATETIME,
    ToTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @ShiftTable TABLE
(
    FromDateTime DATETIME,
    ToDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @ShiftTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 07:30:00.000','2018-05-02 12:30:00.000')
INSERT INTO @ShiftTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 01:30:00.000','2018-05-02 16:30:00.000')

INSERT INTO @InsideOutsideTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 07:24:00.000','2018-05-02 11:47:00.000')
INSERT INTO @InsideOutsideTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 18:07:00.000','2018-05-02 18:32:00.000')
```

Below is my query to bring the shifts which employee not attended.

```
SELECT
    S.*
FROM @ShiftTable S
CROSS APPLY @InsideOutsideTable T
WHERE S.FromDateTime NOT BETWEEN T.FromTime AND T.ToTime
AND S.ToDateTime NOT BETWEEN T.FromTime AND T.ToTime
```

But it is returning every row. Can you help me achieve my requirement?

Expected output:

```
FromDateTime               ToDateTime
2018-05-02 01:30:00.000    2018-05-02 16:30:00.000
```

A big thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you missing an Employee key from your sample data?

Comment: I do have in main tables. Since this question is only for a logic, I have given here only datetime stamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use this

```
   DECLARE @InsideOutsideTable TABLE 
(
    FromTime DATETIME,
    ToTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @ShiftTable TABLE
(
    ID Int,
    FromDateTime DATETIME,
    ToDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @ShiftTable VALUES (1,'2018-05-02 07:30:00.000','2018-05-02 12:30:00.000')
INSERT INTO @ShiftTable VALUES (2,'2018-05-02 13:30:00.000','2018-05-02 16:30:00.000')

INSERT INTO @InsideOutsideTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 07:24:00.000','2018-05-02 11:47:00.000')
INSERT INTO @InsideOutsideTable VALUES ('2018-05-02 18:07:00.000','2018-05-02 18:32:00.000')


SELECT S.*
FROM @ShiftTable S
WHERE ID NOT IN (
SELECT
    S.ID
FROM @ShiftTable S
INNER JOIN @InsideOutsideTable T
ON      (    ( T.FromTime <= S.ToDateTime  AND   T.FromTime >= S.FromDateTime )
                        OR ( T.ToTime <= S.ToDateTime  AND     T.ToTime >= S.FromDateTime )
                        OR ( T.FromTime <= S.FromDateTime AND T.ToTime >= S.ToDateTime )
                    )  
            AND     T.FromTime <= S.ToDateTime  
            )
```

**take care that you defined 1:30 not 13:30**

Comment: This as well brings all rows

Comment: those two shifts are interacted !!

Comment: First shift 07:30 to 12:30 and there is a check-in happened in between this timings. Employee came in at 07:24 and went out at 11:47. He attended this shift. Second shift 01:30 PM to 04:30 PM. There is no check-in happened in between this shift. I would like to return that

Comment: i've updated my answer , take care that you defined 1:30 not 13:30

Comment: I see your updated answer but it doesn't bring any output. :-(

Comment: i just run this code in sql server , and i got 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
        S.*,
        (SELECT 
             count(*)
         FROM @InsideOutsideTable T 
         WHERE T.FromTime BETWEEN S.FromDateTime AND S.ToDateTime
           OR T.ToTime BETWEEN S.FromDateTime AND S.ToDateTime) AS cnt
    FROM @ShiftTable S) AS tbl
WHERE cnt = 0
```

Comment: This query brings first shift every the employee attends. First shift 07:30 to 12:30 and there is a check-in happened in between this timings. There is no check-in happened in between 01:30 PM and 04:30PM, second shift timing. I would like to return that.

Comment: I thought attend means all duration of check-in must occurred in duration of shift but you are right every overlap of check-in and shift time means attend, so i changed AND to OR in where condition of query that bring all attend, it must work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for full overlaps between between the two tables. 
 If so,the simplest approach is a `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT S.*
FROM @ShiftTable S LEFT JOIN
     @InsideOutsideTable T
     ON S.FromDateTime <= T.FromTime AND
        S.ToDateTime >= T.ToTime 
WHERE T.ToTime IS NULL;
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/KQJ3381).